# How to pass a function from a list of function to another function with in a function?

Tags: r, function

I want to pass a list of functions to a function which passes each of the functions to a second function. The following code works for a single function but does not work for a list of functions.

```
df <- as.data.frame(...)
parameters <- list(c(1,2), c(1,2)
model_1 <- function(parameters, df){...}
model_2 <- function(parameters, df){...}
models <- c(model_1, model_2)

find_the_best_model <- function(models, df, parameters){
    est <- rep(0, length(models))
    for (i in 1:length(models)){
       model <- models[1]
       parameter <- as.numeric(unlist(parameters[i])
       est[i] <- optim(par = parameter , fn = model, data = df)
    }
    return(est)
}

find_the_best_model(models, df, parameters)
```

How do I pass a list of functions to the above function?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: If you have multiple models to test you might consider using a for loop instead of putting all the models into the same function?

Answer (score 0):

To find the best model, you need to compare the results of the estimations. Note that you cant store the results of `optim` in a vector, because it returns multiple values in a list. I would propose something like

```
find_the_best_model <- function(models, df, parameters){
  
  optimResultList <- lapply(1:length(models), function(i) {
    functionToOptimizeDependingOnlyOnParameter <- function(par) {
      models[[i]](parameters = par, df = df)
    }
    optim(par = unlist(parameters[[i]]), fn = functionToOptimizeDependingOnlyOnParameter)
  })
  
  functionValues <- sapply(optimResultList,"[[","value")
  bestModelIndex <- which.min(functionValues)
  return(models[[bestModelIndex]])
}
```

Naming is hopefully clear such that you undertsand what is happening.